# Using DualShock 4 from OS X

Tags: macos, swift, playstation

On a whim I bought a Sony DualShock 4 Wireless game controller. Pairing the controller with my mac was easy. The controller works as expected in OpenEmu.

Now I want to use the controller in my own game. In an XCode playground, I tried this:

```
import Cocoa;
import GameController;

print(GCController.controllers())
print(GCController.controllers().count)
```

The output is:
    []
    0

This means that the DualShock controller wasn't registered as a GCController.

Should it?

Is there some kind of initialization that needs to be done before invoking controllers?

An example is Objective-C or Swift would be welcome.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes and no. The DualShock 4-controller is not supported by Apple's framework. I have some code here with references to more information. The general structure of the code seems okay - but I think there were a bug - somewhere... https://github.com/soegaard/dualshock4/blob/master/dualshock4.rkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though [DualShock 4 support was added to the Game Controller framework in 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/616/). This is working for me on macOS 11.1.

However, it looks as though the controller doesn't show up in the initial call to `GCController.controllers()`. You need to register for [GCControllerDidConnect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1458856-gccontrollerdidconnect) notifications and then the controller will show up (for both USB and Bluetooth connections).

Answer (score 2):

There's a tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=10339 but that seems to suggest that the DualShock 4 isn't supported by the GameController framework.

See the Apple documentation, I would begin here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/DiscoveringControllers/DiscoveringControllers.html which explains how to discover and connect to controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The comments to Ray Wenderlich's blog post suggests the problem is that the DualShock 4 controller is supported by the GameController framework. The documentation says to call the class method `controllers` which is what I did in the example. The other methods is as far as I can tell, meant to be used to get information about controllers being added or removed later on.

Comment: "is supported" -> "is not supported"